# Dynamic rel Selector not working

Tags: jquery, dynamic, attr, rel

I am using jquery to dynamically create an active state using Flexslider's API. Here is my jQuery:

```
var curslide = slider.animatingTo;
var parsed = parseInt(curslide);

$("#pillarControl li").each(function(){
     $(this).removeClass("active");
});

$("#pillarControl  li a[rel='parsed']").parent().addClass("active");
```

THe bottom line is NOT working. If I replace `parsed` with an actual integer, it works great. But for some reason, the variable `parsed` is not causing the active class to be added. I did a test to see if the variable `parsed` had the correct value stored, and it does. Seems to be a syntax problem? Not sure, any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you don't pass the variable value, but just 'parsed' as text. Try:

```
$("#pillarControl  li a[rel='" + parsed + "']").parent().addClass("active");
```

Comment: Forgot to concatenate! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#pillarControl  li a[rel='" + parsed + "']").parent().addClass("active");
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be passing **parsed** as a string . You need to pass the

```
var parsed = parseInt(curslide);
```

So your old selector is looking with `rel="parsed"`  and not the value of parsed..

```
$("#pillarControl  li a[rel='" + parsed + "']").parent().addClass("active");
```